# what happened to sun.* packages

Tags: java

I don't find any references in JDK 7 documentation regarding `sun.*` packages.
Is it deprecated. But then what are the substitutes?

For eg: `sun.reflect.*;` is deprecated, so what are the options now?

It would be great if someone could post the deprecated packages and the new options available.

Note: I succeded in using them by setting access rules to all available.
[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Why would you need them? Are you trying to implement caller sensitive behavior?

Comment: As far as I know, the `sun.*` packages were never officially released, so if you're using them they may vary between releases.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `java.lang.reflect` package for reflection purposes.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html

Comment: I don't see a substitute for sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with this `ReflectionFactory` what you cannot achieve with the things out of the `java.lang.reflect` package?

Answer (score 1):

The `sun.reflect` packages are not deprecated. They are for internal use by the JDK only. Oracle (formerly Sun) does not document the internal packages and does not guarantee that they will exist on all Java platform implementations (any vendor can make a Java platform implementation) nor that they will be the same in all versions of the standard Oracle Java platform implementation.

[Oracle explains this on their website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html):

> **The `sun.*` packages are not part of the supported, public interface.**
>
> A Java program that directly calls into `sun.*` packages is not
>   guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a
>   program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same
>   platform.

Comment: are there any other packages? with similar fate?

Comment: On the page linked in my answer it also says: "The java.*, javax.* and org.* packages documented in the Java Platform Standard Edition API Specification make up the official, supported, public interface." so anything outside those 3 packages, including "com.sun.*" is not supported.

Comment: Here's the Javadoc of ReflectionFactory from the OpenJDK 1.7 source code: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/reflect/ReflectionFactory.html

Comment: What do you want to do with ReflectionFactory that is not part of the normal reflection API?

Comment: a little hacking... ;-)

Comment: Why didn't you say so? ;-) Have a look at [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) when you get bored with reflection ;-)